# Is it possible to get a files owner url metadata in the macOS terminal?

Tags: terminal, scripting, operating-system, metadata, photoshop

I can access the meta data property "owner url" thru Photoshop, but am hoping that there's a way to access it from the command line without having to open the file.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

`mdls` doesn't list this particular metadata field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in command line tool to achieve this.

However, you can utilize [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), which is a platform-independent Perl library plus a command-line application for reading, writing and editing meta information in a wide variety of files.

---

### Installation:

The guidelines for installing it on macOS can be found [here](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX). In summary:

> 1. **Download** the **ExifTool OS X Package** from the [ExifTool home page](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html).
>
>    *(The file you download should be named `ExifTool-11.17.dmg`.)*
> 2. **Install** as a normal **OS X package**.
>
>    (Open the disk image, double-click on the install package, and
>      follow the instructions.)
>
> You can now run exiftool by typing `exiftool` in a Terminal window.

---

### Processing a single file:

1. #### Reading the *"owner url"* via the command line:

   Run the following command in a Terminal window:

   ```
   $ exiftool -b −xmp:WebStatement ~/Desktop/path/to/image.psd
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** the `~/Desktop/path/to/image.psd` part in the command above should be replaced with a real image filepath.</sub>

   This command will log the URL to the console only if the image metadata contains one. For instance:

   > *https://www.example.com*
2. #### Writing the *"owner url"* via the command line:

   You can also write the *"owner url"* to a file by running the following command:

   ```
   $ exiftool −xmp:WebStatement="https://www.foobar.com" ~/Desktop/path/to/image.psd
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** As mentioned previously, the `~/Desktop/path/to/image.psd` part in the command above should be replaced with a real image filepath, and the `https://www.foobar.com` part should be replaced with the actual URL you want to apply.</sub>

---

### Processing multiple files:

1. #### Reading the "owner url" for multiple files via the command line:

   If you wanted to read the *"owner url"* for all image files within a given folder, (including those in sub folders), and generate a JSON report you can run the following command:

   ```
   $ exiftool -j -r −xmp:WebStatement ~/Desktop/path/to/folder/ -ext jpg -ext png -ext psd -ext tif > ~/Desktop/owner-urls.json
   ```

   **Breakdown of command (above):**

   - **`-j`** - Use JSON formatting for output.
   - **`-r`** - Recursively process sub directories.
   - **`−xmp:WebStatement`** - Retrieve the *WebStatement* value, i.e. *"owner url"*.
   - **`~/Desktop/path/to/folder/`** - The path to the folder containing images (This should be replaced with a real path to a folder).
   - **`-ext jpg -ext png -ext psd -ext tif`** - The file extension(s) to process.
   - **`> ~/Desktop/owner-urls.json`** - Save the JSON output to file at the *Desktop* named *owners-url.json*.

Comment: Is there a way to install exiftool in the local account, I don't have admin access, and would rather not need it.

Comment: The note at top of [this page](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX) says: _"ExifTool does not need to be installed to run"_. You could try the following steps: **1)** Download full Perl distribution from link at top of [this page](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html), (i.e. from this [link](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/Image-ExifTool-11.17.tar.gz). **2)** Extract _Image-ExifTool-11.17.tar.gz_, lets say to your Desktop folder. **3)** Then run the command in Terminal like this:  `~/Desktop/Image-ExifTool-11.17/exiftool` etc...